# Issue extracting URI and Response Time from logs

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex pattern for extracting the URI and response time from application logs to be used with Google Cloud Ops Agent for ingestion into Cloud Logging. However, I am facing difficulties in capturing the response time.

Regex Pattern:

```
(?<requestedURI>/api[\d\s?]+)(?:[\s]+)? (?<requestProcessedTime>\d+)\s*$
```

Sample Log Record:

```
12:57:03.106 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-9] INFO test-access-logger localhost.internal [24/Jan/2024:12:57:03 +0000] GET /api/test/user/session?timestamp=1706101022929 HTTP/1.1 200 40 25
```

Expected Output:

```
/api/test/user/session 25
```

I have successfully matched the requested URI, but I'm facing issues capturing the request processed time, which should be '25' in this case.

Any help or suggestions on how to modify the regex pattern to achieve the desired result would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to match the required URI and response time using this regex pattern - `(?<requestedURI>\/api[^\d\s?]+)(?:[^\s]+)? \S+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(?<requestProcessedTime>\d+)$`